# Emoji mb_detect_encoding() error when updating to latest Craft 2.6.x

Tags: error, bug

I updated a Craft 2.6 installation to the latest 2.6.x and suddenly I get an error when saving a user's profile on the frond end:

```
mb_detect_encoding() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
/data/sites/web/boumaticdevbuthostcom/subsites/corporate-web.boumatic.dev.buthost.com/craft/app/vendor/elvanto/litemoji/src/LitEmoji.php(108)
```

However, nowhere on that page has an emoji been inserted in any input fields or anything.

I hope somebody can help me with this as it is an urgent issue.

**UPDATE**

I just tracked down the problem to this input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields[gdprPermissionsList][permissionSales][type]" value="permissionInfo">
```

Which is quite weird as it does the exact same thing as 3 other fields on that page which work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was with this field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields[gdprPermissionsList][permissionSales][fields][lastChangedDate][date]" value="{{ now|date("m/d/Y") }}">
```

The `[date]` part was to much and it saved the value in Craft as a literal string: `{"date":"07\/11\/2018"}` instead of the formatted date.

In one of the Craft updates that throws an error, maybe because it ses it as an object/array due to the curly brackets or maybe because that string has an emoji shortcut in it?